# Plack::Builder get post

Tags: perl, plack, psgi

Is there a way to specify in the builder section of a particular method (GET or POST), but not both at once?
My example of builder section.

```
my $main_app=builder
{
    mount "/" => builder{$app;};
};
```

It handles get and post requests, how can I disable the processing of GET requests?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plack::Builder does not provide a native way to route requests based on HTTP method. Writing a middleware handling specific methods should be quite simple. For example something like

```
my $post_app = ...;

my $main = builder {
    enable sub {
        my $app = shift;
        sub {
            my $env = shift;

            if ($env->{REQUEST_METHOD} eq "POST") {
                return $post_app->($env);
            }

            return $app->($env);
        }
    };

    ....;
};
```

Existing frameworks based om PSGI might provide better alternatives for routing requests based om HTTP method. For example it looks easy to do with Dancer.